# How can I create box cells in the form of half of 6×6 matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

[image]

Looking for some ways to write a half matrix with box cells. My aim is to write like things in the picture.

Comment: Welcome! If you do not need the arrows, a simple tabular will suffice. Otherwise a tikz matrix or using tikzmark might provide a possible path.

Comment: Welcome. IMHO the arrows in the matrix are not so-well arranged. The formatting of the arrows in the picture above is really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility to get the shape and arrows. No attempt reproducing the texts have been made, I am not very good at typing because I only have claws.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{|p{1cm}}|}
\hline
\makecell[lb]{
\tikzmarknode{S1}{S:0}\\
T:1\\
X:2
} & \makecell[lb]{
S:0\\
T:2\\
X:4
} & xyz &  abc &  def\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & abc & uvw & stu & \makecell[lb]{
S:1\\
T:1\\
\tikzmarknode{X3}{X:2}
} \\
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}  & uvw & \makecell[lb]{
S:0\\
T:2\\
X:4
} & fgh \\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   & \makecell[lb]{
S:0\\
T:2\\
X:4
} & fgh \\
\cline{4-5}
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   & \makecell[lb]{
S:0\\
T:2\\
X:4
} \\
\cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-latex] (S1) -- (X3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]